# Python NLTK exercise: chapter 5

Tags: python, nltk, tagging

Hy guys,
I'm starting to study NLTK following the official book from the NLTK team.

I'm in chapter 5-"Tagging"- and I can't resolve one of the excercises at page 186 of  the PDF version:

*Given the list of past participles specified by cfd2['VN'].keys(), try to collect a list of all the word-tag pairs that immediately precede items in that list.*

I tried this way:

```
wsj = nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_words(simplify_tags=True)

[wsj[wsj.index((word,tag))-1:wsj.index((word,tag))+1] for (word,tag) in wsj if word in cfd2['VN'].keys()]
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.py", line 401, in iterate_from
for tok in piece.iterate_from(max(0, start_tok-offset)):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.py", line 295, in iterate_from
self._stream.seek(filepos)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

I think I'm doing something wrong in accessing the wsj structure, but I can't figure out what is wrong!

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wsj` is of type `nltk.corpus.reader.util.ConcatenatedCorpusView` that behaves like a list (this is why you can use functions like `index()`), but "behind the scenes" NLTK never reads the whole list into memory, it will only read those parts from a file object that it needs. It seems that if you iterate over a CorpusView object and use `index()` (which requires iterating again) at the same time, the file object will return `None`.

This way it works, though it is less elegant than a list comprehension:

```
  for i in range(len(wsj)):
    if wsj[i][0] in cfd2['VN'].keys():
      print wsj[(i-1):(i+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both the index call and the slicing cause an exception:

```
wsj = nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_words(simplify_tags=True)
cfd2 = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((t,w) for w,t in wsj)
wanted = cfd2['VN'].keys()

# just getting the index -> exception before 60 items
for w, t in wsj:
    if w in wanted:
        print wsj.index((w,t))

# just slicing -> sometimes finishes, sometimes throws exception
for i, (w,t) in enumerate(wsj):
    if w in wanted:
        print wsj[i-1:i+1]
```

I'm guessing it's caused by accessing previous items in a stream that you are iterating over.

It works fine if you iterate once over `wsj` to create a list of indices and use them in a second iteration to grab the slices:

```
results = [
    wsj[j-1:j+1]
    for j in [
        i for i, (w,t) in enumerate(wsj)
        if w in wanted
    ]
]
```

As a side note: calling `index` without a `start` argument will return the first match every time.

Answer (score 0):

`wsj` is of type `ConcatenatedCorpusView`, and I think it is choking on an empty tuple `('.', '.')`. The easiest solution is to cast `ConcatenatedCorpusView` to a `list` explicitly. You can do that by doing:

`wsj = list(wsj)`

Iteration works fine then. Getting the index of a duplicate item is a separate problem. See: https://gist.github.com/denten/11388676